# DNSSEC - Do we have to store keys after we signed zones with them?

Tags: dnssec

I'm now working on WMbind and I'm making a new module called 'signedzone' . And, I added one more table to wmbind database which is a keys table. So, as the questions asked above, do we have to store keys(in this case, I mean both KSK and ZSK) after we use them to sign the zone?

I have tried deleting those used keys before and it didn't do anything to the signed zones.

However, I just need to know if deleting used keys will affect zones that are signed with them.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

A DNSSEC signed zone only has the public portion of a key pair, so deleting the key will not impact the zone at all.  In general, it is a bad idea to delete the keys because you will likely need them in the future.

Deleting the private portion will prevent you from re-signing the zone with those keys when you make changes or when the RRSIGs need to be updated (RRSIGs have a validity period and will become invalid).  If the keys are gone, you will need to re-do everything and if you uploaded a DS RR to the parent DNS zone, you will need to update that as well with new KSK.

Like any private key, DNSSEC keys should be protected, but should be stored for their entire lifecycle.